# How to get parent id(root parent) from child id

Tags: php, recursion, hierarchical-trees

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [function returning only once, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348229/function-returning-only-once-why)

my Database structure looks like

```
id|parent|
1 |   0  |
2 |   0  |
3 |   0  |
4 |   1  |
5 |   4  |
6 |   5  |
```

I am in need of a function that gets parent(i.e parent=0) for a id as parameter
For eg .. get_parent(6)==returns 1
I did some research and found this question

[How can I recursively obtain the "parent ID" of rows in this MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006974/how-can-i-recursively-obtain-the-parent-id-of-rows-in-this-mysql-table)

I tried making this function

```
    function get_parent_id($cid,$found=array())
    {
     array_push($found,$cid);
     $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_destinations WHERE id=$cid";
     $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ($sql);
     if(mysql_num_rows($result))
     {

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
        $found[] = get_parent_id($row['parent'], $found);
        }
     }
return $found;
       }
```

I make a call by

```
$fnd=get_parent_id();
$array_reverse($fnd);
$parent_root=$fnd['0'];
```

But my method is wrong. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You really shouldn't *double* post. You should ensure you receive your answer for the original question.

Comment: even though . I would be very glad if any one could provide me the answer besides telling me the rules and regulation. Sorry for being rude..I need answer of this question desperately

Comment: please try to understand http://de.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data

Comment: you don't want it's direct parent ... you want to navigate all the way up the tree until it is a root node, correct? just do a recursive loop getting each parent until the parent = 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to get the parent ID within the SQL query, or using PHP?  If you're looking at using PHP for it, you could either do `$arr[6]['parent']` assuming you got the information from the database into an array.  Or, you could have a function:

```
<?php
//Let's assume you have your data from the database as such
$arr = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'parent' => 0),
    array('id' => 2, 'parent' => 0),
    array('id' => 3, 'parent' => 0),
    array('id' => 4, 'parent' => 1),
    array('id' => 5, 'parent' => 4),
    array('id' => 6, 'parent' => 5));

function get_key($arr, $id)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if ($val['id'] === $id) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function get_parent($arr, $id)
{
    $key = get_key($arr, $id);
    if ($arr[$key]['parent'] == 0)
    {
        return $id;
    }
    else 
    {
        return get_parent($arr, $arr[$key]['parent']);
    }
}

echo get_parent($arr, 6);
?>
```

Note that the code is untested, and just a sample.

Comment: he wants the "root" parent. so not the direct parent. you need to recurse until you get $arr[$id]['parent'] = 0, and then return $id;

Comment: ya I want the root parent. and @mikeMurko I am trying to make that. If I do that I will put my answers here. I am almost very close to getting answer. but am getting confused by tree hierarchy

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense then, I've updated my answer to demonstrate what you're looking for.  I've tested and verified it works as expected.

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help.  Let me know if you need any explanation of the code as I didn't comment it.