# Find the parent of the id until the condition is true

Tags: php, mysql, recursive-query

I have a table named `member` with the structure below.

```
+----+-----------+-------------+  
| id | parent_id | status      |  
+----+-----------+-------------+  
|  1 |         0 | DISTRIBUTOR |  
|  2 |         1 | DISTRIBUTOR |   
|  3 |         2 | DISTRIBUTOR |  
|  4 |         2 | RETAILER    |  
|  5 |         4 | RETAILER    |  
|  6 |         5 | DISTRIBUTOR |  
+----+-----------+-------------+
```

now I want to find the parent `id`. For example, if I select `id` 6 then it will show that the parent id of 6 is 5, but the twist is this: if I selected the **id 6** since the status of it's **parent 5 is RETAILER** it will go up to check what is the parent_id of **id 5** but since the parent _id of 5 which is **id 4 is RETAILER** it will go up again and check the parent_id of **id 4** since the parent_id of 4 is **2 and status DISTRIBUTOR** the conditon will stop and it will output that the parent_id of **id 6** is the **id 2**

**Edit** (Query given by user in Comment section)

```
SELECT id, parent_id, status FROM member WHERE id=6.
```

Comment: SELECT id, parent_id, status FROM member WHERE id='6'.
I didn't have any idea on how to get the result that I want that will find the next parent_id until the condition is true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get parent id(root parent) from child id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349877/how-to-get-parent-idroot-parent-from-child-id)

Comment: yes but the difference is how can I skip the parent_id if RETAILER and continue until the condition meet the DISTRIBUTOR

Comment: yes like a **chain nodes** looking for the first parent_id status that match to DISTRIBUTOR status. so it will skip the parent_id with the status RETAILER

Comment: we can not apply/call query recursively..like in programming language. still you can fetch all the record and by creating recursive function(like in PHP or any other language) you can able to get your result

Comment: I think you need to use a [stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16513418/2032498) to emulate a recursive query, or refactor your database.

Comment: As Amit says, MySQL has no native support for recursion. Instead, choices include, but are not limited to, the following:
- Join the table to itself as many times as could possibly be required
- Handle the recursion at the application level, e.g. with a PHP loop 
- Use a Stored Procedure to handle the recursion
- Switch to a Nested Set (or some sort of hybrid model) instead of the 'so-called' Adjacency List model

All of these solutions are discussed more thoroughly elsewhere, including a number of excellent, popular, and hence easily googled, articles on Hierarchical data and MySQL.

Comment: thanks! I am doing now with PHP loop, I will post the update of my code.

Comment: If you want to do it in `mysql` - maybe useful? [Manage hierarchical data with MySQL stored procedures](http://moinne.com/blog/ronald/mysql/manage-hierarchical-data-with-mysql-stored-procedures)

Comment: thanks for the link @RyanVincent